# How can a diffused(frosted) glass be modelled in path tracing

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, material

How can a diffused(frosted) glass be modelled in path tracing?

Currently I am able to define a window poly line as a clear glass material where it transmits or reflects the ray. I am not clear though how it should work if the sheet of glass is frosted(diffuse transmission?).

[image]

Comment: If you know how diffuse reflection works (ie not a specular mirror like reflection), what that does with reflected rays, you do with refracted rays.

Comment: Keep the same parameters, but increase the roughness.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. it shed light on how I got it wrong first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you are familiar with the concept of BSDFs, the usual way of modelling rough dielectric surfaces (i.e. glass, water, plastics) is to use microfacet-based models like [Microfacet Models for Refraction through Rough Surfaces](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~srm/publications/EGSR07-btdf.html).

To make it work efficiently in a path tracer you will need a good sampling strategy, like [Importance Sampling Microfacet-Based BSDFs using the Distribution of Visible Normals](http://www.eugenedeon.com/project/importance-sampling-microfacet-based-bsdfs-using-the-distribution-of-visible-normals/).

Also keep in mind, that the mentioned BSDF model tends to get darker as you increase roughness because it neglects the light which gets inter-reflected among micro-facets. This can be compensated, but it's not a trivial thing to do.